# Adding the numbers inside of an array together

Tags: java, arrays

I am stuck at this part right now with adding the groups together. So like, Array1 A + Array2 A
Array1 B + Array 2 B

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Math {
    public static final int ARRAY1 = 5;
    public static final int ARRAY2 = 5;
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int de;
    de = 1;
    System.out.println("Welcome! This program will assist you in\n 1) Adding groups of numbers\n 2) and subtracting a group of numbers\nPlease enter the number of which you need help with!");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    op = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (op == 1) {
        System.out.println("****Addition****\nAwesome! Please insert all the numbers for your first group of numbers!");
        System.out.println("Enter "+ARRAY1+"");
        int[] array = new int[ARRAY1];
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter value "+i);
            array[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Great! Now please enter your "+ARRAY2+" other group numbers!");
        int[] array1 = new int[ARRAY2];
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter value "+i);
            array1[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    
    }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the array of the same size and then loop over adding the elements one by one from the 2 input arrays.

```
int[] sum_array = new int[ARRAY1]; // initialize the output array
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    sum_array[i] = array[i] + array1[i]; // adding the elements from two arrays
}
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    System.out.print(sum_array[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to create another array, let's call it `array3`, with the same length as your 2 arrays. Then loop over the array3 and store the sum of `array1[index]` and `array2[index]` in the `array3[index]`